# How to execute initializers lazily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, lazy-loading

When there're a lot of gems in the `Gemfile` Rails' boot time is pretty bad.

But the thing is that we don't always need to load all of the gems.

- The `rake db:migrate` (and friends) don't really need anything non-ActiveRecord related (maybe not even).
- The `rails c` on the other hand probably needs most of it.
- The `rake assets:precompile` probably doesn't need much at all.
- Etc.

Unfortunately the `initializers` are pretty tightly bound to the gems (for example simple_form configuration should be done when simple_form is required, thus will faile with `gem 'simple_form', require: false`).

So the question is what is the best way to **execute all the initializers lazily** to improve boot time, but still not break anything.

Answer (score 2):

You have full control of the gems that Bundler loads at startup. In your application.rb you will find the following:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
end
```

You can modify it slightly to react to an ENV variable in order to tell bundler to load a simplified subset of your gems.

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  if ENV['RAKE_ENV']
    Bundler.require :rake
  else
    Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  end
end
```

Now, you can toggle your initializers by checking if the environment variable is set.

In your Gemfile you will have to create a group called 'rake', the same way you create 'development' and 'test' groups.